# How to drop a dataset from a 2d DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, drop

I would like to delete a row/column from a 2d DataFrame.
Let's assume the DataFrame looks like this:

```
animal   cat  dog  hedgehog
time
  0       1    1      0
  1       2    0      1
```

How to get rid of let's say the whole dog thingy to get something like that:

```
animal   cat hedgehog
time
  0       1    0
  1       2    1
```

I tried e.g. `df.drop()` with a lot of variations but haven't fully understood pandas yet.

Comment: have you tried `df.drop(['dog'],axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
df.drop('dog',axis=1)
```

will drop it.You need to pass an axis.
If you want this drop operation to effect current df , use `inplace` keyword.

```
df.drop('dog',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

If you want to drop more than one column, then pass a list.

```
df.drop(['dog','cat'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the column, like this

```
df.drop(columns='dog', inplace=True)
```

and also you can remove many columns one time, like this

```
df.drop(columns=['dog', 'cat'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: How is this answer different from that of @solac34 ?

Comment: @ScottC - hi, it has difference about 'axis'. my answer is doesn't need axis value. because it already has.